# How to filter Users that meet CASE criteria without nesting WHERE in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Right now I have a query that lets me know which users didn't make a purchase 12 months prior to becoming members. These users have MEM_PRE_12=0 and I want to filter off those users more natively using SQL partitions rather than always putting rudimentary WHERE criteria.

Here is the SQL I use to find the users I want/don't want.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATE <= DATEADD(month, -12, U.INSERTED_AT) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MEM_PRE_12, I.CLIENTID, I.INSTALLATIONID
FROM <<<My_Joined_Tables>>>
GROUP BY I.CLIENTID, I.INSTALLATIONID
HAVING MEM_PRE_12 != 0
ORDER BY MEM_PRE_12
```

After this I'm going to have to go back and say where I.CLIENTID in the above nested query and select the actual information I want from users who made purchases greater than their insertion date.

How can I do this without so much nesting of all these joined tables?

Comment: You query has no `WHERE`, so I'm rather baffled about what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the detailed rows for customers who made a purchase in the last 12 months, you can use window functions:

```
with q as (
      <whatever your query logic is>
     )
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN DATE <= DATEADD(month, -12, U.INSERTED_AT) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) over (partition by CLIENTID, INSTALLATIONID) as AS MEM_PRE_12
      from q
     ) q
where mem_pre_12 > 0;
```